Can we refer to "an electrical socket" as "a plug"?
The grammar book has an exercise to change positive sentences to negative:

Ref. Adventures with Grammar and Composition, Beena Sugatham. Oxford Printing Press.
Rewrite these sentences using so -- that and a negative word instead of too.
1.The wire is too short to reach the  plug.

Why did the book use "plug" as opposed to "socket"?

Ref. Cambridge dictionary.
socket
noun [ C ].
(ELECTRICAL).
the part of a piece of equipment, especially electrical equipment, into which another part fits:
an electrical socket.
a light socket.
UK He had forgotten to plug the television into the mains socket.


I understand that the female part (on the wall) is referred to as a socket. If we want to purchase the item, a socket is a socket, and a plug is a plug.
But I have heard a lot of people refer to a socket as a plug in their conversation.
So, can a socket be called a plug?
Edit 1

Plug can Informally called a socket.
Ref. Cambridge dictionary
plug.
mainly UK informal.
an electric socket:
Is there a plug in the bedroom that I can use for my hairdryer?


Strictly speaking, the power (or signal) goes FROM a socket, THROUGH a plug, TO an appliance. But There's a plug on the wall straight down from where the lamp is supposed to go . We could just plug it in there. That's from The Good Neighbor: A Novel Jay Quinn (2014).

And fwiw, in the US, though socket and outlet  are the more common terms for the female gadget in the wall into which the plug’s prongs are introduced, the technically preferred term is receptacle.

@PaulTanenbaum Yes power outlet also. The term used by RS components is Plug socket/ Electrical socket

Setting aside the issue of calling the socket a plug, that's like saying "His legs are too short to reach the ground".   Appliances that plug into wall sockets are portable so it would make no sense to say that such an appliance has a cord that was too short to reach the socket.

The OP is right that the device on the wall is called socket, not plug.  Plugs are the male counterparts, those that have the three pins or sometimes two, depending on the standard adopted.
Sockets incorporated with switches like the two shown here are called switched socket outlets.  This standard is adopted in many countries including mine.
Some countries use a different term, receptacle, which means the same as socket.

Hi @Michael Harvey, these are quite common in the electrical engineering field
I’ve been in my whole life.  See Gender of connectors and fasteners.
I’ve just discovered more interesting terminology,
Genderless (hermaphroditic) and Gender changers, all in the same link.

In the dictionary the meaning of plug is also given as socket informally. –

@James Mathai, I’m not sure how prevalent such alternative naming is, but surely it is not used by any competent technical people.
I’ve never encountered any in my 33 years working as an electrical engineer including 22 years as Professional Engineer.

It is what happened to me also. I was correcting people for calling a socket a plug. But now I found it is accepted informally.

This is possible in an informal, non-technical setting.  For example, a customer is paying for such an item he or she is already holding and says out the item’s name, wrongly.  People may not feel the need to correct him or her as the important thing is that the item is indeed what the customer wants to buy, naming error notwithstanding.   After some times, this alternative naming sticks.

I also have an engineering background and I know if we wish to talk technically a socket is only a socket and not a plug. I am accepting your answer.
